# CasperJS - No redirect (bot detection?) on Site Home Page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

Been playing around with CasperJS on a site (Hyatt.com) and have hit a snag..

Using this simple code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36');

casper.start('http://www.hyatt.com', function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
});

casper.run();
```

All I get returned by CasperJS is a "maintenance page" which is incorrect... a real browser gets a 301 redirect to a proper home page.

I've looked at the headers and can't figure it out.  Not sure if there is some JS in the main page that is not getting executed for some kind of redirect.

Any help on getting through this is appreciated!

Comment: I see the maintenance page too. "Please Excuse Us While We Do a Little Housekeeping ..." Seems that on the first call you see the maintenance page, clear your cache and cookies in you browser to reproduce it. Or call the site twice in casperjs, that should work.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried echoing the contents, doing a thenOpen and still have the same "maintenance" page.  So still at a roadblock unfortunately.

Comment: Seems like they are a bit protected against crawling.